# iPhone Messages app always says my wife has notifications silenced

Tags: iphone, messages, notifications

My wife's phone is a 13 and my phone is a 13 mini. They both have the latest patch level 16.4.1 (a).

Ever since my wife got her latest iPhone last summer, whenever I try to send her a message it says "Wife has notifications silenced". There is a "notify anyways" option. There are many, many articles online explaining how to use the Focus features to get rid of this. Unfortunately it seems there are a multitude of relevant settings.

I have tried them all. I have spent hours with AppleCare Senior advisors going through all the settings. I have confirmed that none of her other Apple devices have Focus enabled, even though the sharing of this setting is also disabled. We have rebooted the phones, reset the phones and tried nearly everything.

The latest from the AppleCare Senior Advisor is that the problem might not be a setting on my wife's phone, but something on my phone. This belief is in part based on the fact that some limited testing by other people with iPhones does not present the "notifications silenced" message. That points to a problem on my phone. So we have gone through a lot of additional troubleshooting on both phones. This now includes Reset All Settings on both phones.

Now they are suggesting a complete reload of iOS. I am not sure that this will help, because this problem existed not only on my current iPhone, but existed on my previous iPhone, which was an iPhone 8. However, it is possible that migrating from the 8 to the 13 did also migrate the problem, so it is not a totally unreasonable plan.

I am still thinking there is some configuration detail which is causing the problem, even though we have many times now "gone through all the settings on both phones" while the Senior Advisor was guiding via a screen share on both phones.